# Using MySQL and PHP to create an editable entry database

Tags: php, mysql

My goal is to create an entry form (addnew.php) that will allow me to later edit the entries made by using a different form (edit.php).

Currently addnew.php makes use of a few text fields and 2 checkboxes and what I'm attempting to do is to insert the information from the forms into a MySQL database. The information from the text fields is inserted into one table and the information from the checkboxes is inserted into a different table.

Now, though, I'm trying to use a 3rd table (if necessary) to make an intersection table that will allow me to use the same format used in addnew.php in the edit form.

So, in other words, addnew.php will have some text fields and check boxes and so will edit.php, the difference being that edit.php will have the information filled in and, in the case of the check boxes, they will be checked and the user will have the option to check more boxes or to uncheck already checked boxes.

The three tables that I have right now are:

```
articles:
id - articletitle - articleorganization - articledate - articleurl

tags:
id - tag_contents

articles_tags:
id - article_id - tag_id
```

And the code for addnew.php is:

```
    <?php
 function renderForm($articletitle, $articleorganization, $articledate, $articleurl, $articletags )
 {
 ?>
. . .
            <td width="20%" align="right"><span class="field">Article Title:</span></td>
            <td width="80%" align="left"><span class="field">
              <input name="articletitle" type="text" value="<?php echo $articletitle; ?>" size="50"/>
            </span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right"><span class="field">Article Author:</span></td>
            <td align="left"><span class="field">
              <input name="articleorganization" type="text" value="<?php echo $articleorganization; ?>" size="50"/>
            </span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right"><span class="field">Access Date:</span></td>
            <td align="left"><span class="field">
              <input name="articledate" type="text" value="MM/DD/YYYY" size="50"/>
            </span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right"><span class="field">Article URL:</span></td>
            <td align="left"><span class="field">
            <input name="articleurl" type="text" value="<?php echo $articleurl; ?>" size="50"/>
            </span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right"><span class="field">Article Tags:</span></td>
            <td align="left"><span class="field">
              <input type="checkbox" name="articletags[]" value="geology" id="articletags_0" />
              <input type="checkbox" name="articletags[]" value="astronomy" id="articletags_1" />
            </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add this Article" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        . . .
</html>
<?php 
 }


 include('settings.php');

 if(count($articletags) > 0)
{
 $articletags_string = implode(",", $articletags);
}

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
 { 

 $articletitle = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['articletitle']));
 $articleorganization = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['articleorganization']));
 $articledate = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['articledate']));
 $articleurl = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['articleurl']));
 $articletags = implode(',', $_POST['articletags']);

 if ($articletitle == '' || $articleorganization == '')
 {

 $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';


 renderForm($articletitle, $articleorganization);
 }
  else
 {

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO articles SET articletitle='$articletitle',
      articleorganization='$articleorganization',
      articledate='$articledate',
      articleurl='$articleurl' ")

$article_id = mysql_insert_id();

mysql_query("INSERT INTO tags SET articletags='$articletags' ");

$tag_id = mysql_insert_id();

mysql_query("INSERT INTO articles_tags SET article_id='$article_id',
      tag_id='$tag_id' ")


 or die(mysql_error()); 

 header("Location:addsuccess.php"); 
 }
  }
    else

  {
   renderForm('','','','','');
  }
?>
```

What I'm now having trouble with is figuring out exactly what to do next (after the 2nd INSERT). I know that I need to set up a relationship, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do that.

I'm assuming I need to store the tags in the `tags` table? But if that's the case, how do I get their ID and insert them as a tag to the article?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of making 2 form pages, just make 1 form page. It doubles your work when you have to change in the future. For example, if a userid was sent to the form page, your fields will be populated and your form will know what id it is (probably through hidden field.)  If no userid is loaded, all the field echos will show blank (because the vars are empty), and the userid can be set to blank in the form, and your receiver php will know it is new because id is missing. (I assume you handle error/sanity/login checks already of course.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are decided on this schema, you should be using the `articles_tags` table as a relationship between entries in the `articles` and the `tags` tables (1..*).  This means that there will be multiple entries in the `articles_tags` table with the same `article_id` and a different `tag_id` for each tag associated with a given article.

Alternatively, you could just keep reference to which article a tag belongs to by adding an `article_id` field to your `tags` table.

Example:

```
articles      |        tags          |        articles_tags
id  title         id  tag_text              a_t_id   a_id   t_id
4  Title1         8 Tagblahblah              1        4      8
5  title2         9  tagccccc                2        4      9
                                             3        5      8
```

So these articles_tags entries mean that article with id 4 has tags with id's 8 & 9.  Tag 8 is also used for article id 5.

This is the standard way in SQL to deal with a many to many relationship `(*..*)`.

Comment: Would the 2nd example you gave work just as well? For my part, I'd like to reduce the complexity of the database by as much as possible without sacrificing usability and scalability. The target environment for this database is about 10 people using it (total, not simultaneously) and holding no more than a thousand articles with 4 to 5 tags each.

Comment: If my assumption that there is 1 article having MANY tags is correct, then yes.  If there is a possibility of 1 tag being associated with more than 1 article, then no (you'll need the 'swing' table).

Comment: Yes there is the possibility of both 1 article having many tags and of each tag being applied to multiple articles. So in this case I do need the 3rd table. That's fine with me. Do you think you could provide a small example of how I would be doing this? I can't for the life of me get my head around the logic.

Comment: @bleam So, in this example, I need to have the tag ID already before I begin to process the form, correct? So, if I have a checkbox in my form, and the value is, say "geology", I would also have in the tags table, say, geology with the id=10. And in the POST statement I post the article title to articles, and then I get the id of the tag and set it to variable1, and then use mysql_insert_id to get the ID of the article, and set it to a variable2 and then POST variable1 and variable2 to the articles_tags table....is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that explanation make sense to me.  1) You will need either an Article or a Tag in existence and know its ID.  2) Create the other element (either Article or Tag, whichever is not yet created) and get its ID using mysql_insert_id(). 3) Bind the two IDs together in the Articles_Tags table.  ** Note that steps 2 & 3 can be performed at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql_insert_id() to get last inserted record ID.